# JQUERY - drag and scroll (same photoshop navigator palette)

Tags: jquery, scroll, drag

I have this script http://jsfiddle.net/gphp/ZMmRv/4/

I have two events:
1 - the div is draggable and his movement scrolls the page
2 - Scroll the page moves the div

there are a crash with these two events together. 
it is possible to apply one at a time. start and stop event? how?

thanks

Comment: this is the new script http://jsfiddle.net/gphp/ZMmRv/4/
when i drag there is a crash because when i drag the scroll position of body increases and accordingly the div position......exponentially!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i think is not the better solution but your can take this as a start and edit at your will:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qqn57/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#drag').css({
        'height': ($(document).height()/10),
        'width': ($(document).width()/10)
    });

    $("#drag").draggable({
        scrollSensitivity: 50,
        scrollSpeed: 10
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if( $('#drag').offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() )
            $("#drag").animate({top: $(window).scrollTop()}, "fast");

        if( $('#drag').offset().left < $(window).scrollLeft() )
            $("#drag").animate({left: $(window).scrollLeft()}, "fast");
    });        
});
```

Comment: thanks.. but it works only for first event... demo > http://jsfiddle.net/gphp/ZMmRv/4/

Comment: @GiovanniLudwigPeter You want to scroll the 'black box' with the mouse wheel? You want to drag n' move n' drop the 'black box' only inside the grey box ?
Why are you using the `animate()` inside `draggable()` if it already scroll the page ?

Comment: @GiovanniLudwigPeter You want to scroll the 'black box' with the mouse wheel? You want to drag n' move n' drop the 'black box' only inside the grey box ?

Comment: yes, both. 
when i drag the black box i want to scroll the page.

Comment: @GiovanniLudwigPeter: Sorry but it still not clear for me. But I'll try something.

Comment: thank you. I would create the same animation of the photoshop navigator http://goo.gl/cHDNF when i can drag the box and move the window.... and when I scroll the window, update the box position